# How Can I convert my csv files pixel data into image

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, neural-network

I am totally beginner in this field. I started working with neural network for image classification purpose. My question is I loaded one row through panda. now I want to see that image like from which category it is. it has label 0. so how i can convert that pixels values into image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import cv2
import os

#import deep learning libraries
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

df = pd.read_csv(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/fe/icml_face_data.csv", nrows = 1)
df.pixel

0    70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121...
Name: pixel, dtype: object
```

The above pixel values I am getting now in next step I want to convert this into image.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualise an image using matplotlib (`plt.imshow`) or seaborn (`sns.heatmap`). Note that in all cases you'll probably want to [change the colour map to something other than the default.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

However, it looks like your image is stored in a vector, not a 2D matrix. You can reshape this using numpy (`np.reshape`) but you will need to know the original dimensions of your image for this transformation. You can use `df.pixel.to_numpy()` to make a numpy vector.